# Invalid Request YII when delete model via POST

Tags: yii

I want delete my model via post , but I always get Invalid Request
this is my view

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Delete image'), array('gambar/delete', 'id' => $data->id), array(
        'submit' => array('data/delete', 'id' => $data->id),
        'class' => 'delete', 'confirm' => 'This will remove the image. Are you sure?'
            )
    );
    ?>
```

and this is my action in `GambarController`

```
public function actionDelete() {
    if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel()->delete();

        if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400, 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}
```

But I always get Invalid Request, I have read some forums, but I cannot get it. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you can not use link (`<a>`) to `POST`. Instead, use the `<form>` like this

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/gambar/delete/'.$model->id);?>" method="post">
    <button 
        type="submit"
        name="id"
        value="<?php echo $model->id?>"
        onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure to delete this image?')) return false;">
        <i class="icon-white icon-trash"></i> Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CHtml::link`, this will generate an  html `<a>` tag. When you click on a `<a>`, your browser send **HTTP GET request**(not POST request) to the server. So `if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)` is always `false` and therefore you see Invalid request error. You should remove this condition from the action. Also, `$this->loadModel()->delete()` is invalid, because `loadModel` get an id as parameter. So `$this->loadModel($_GET['id'])->delete()` is correct.

Comment: What I want is to use POST,  but you give is how to use GETt, do you know how to use the post?

Comment: There is not any way for using links with POST. POST is for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

`$this->loadModel(primarykey, 'TableName')->delete();`

Should work!